# java velocity used to generate class files based on mysql tables

Tags: java, orm, code-generation, velocity

How can I generate java class files that are based on mysql database tables?

I have seen some velocity templating examples but nothing that reads a mysql db table and generates a class file from it.

The key is getting the table schema information and looping through the columns etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do that yourself instead of letting a tool like hbm2ddl do it?

Comment: because I'm not using hibernate?

Comment: That was just an example, as I said: a tool _like_ hbm2ddl. If you tell us what framework you're using we might suggest such a tool. If you don't use an existing framework, then why not?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Telosys**, a lightweight code generator based on Velocity. It does exactly what you need.

This generator is able to connect to your database to create a "Database model" then you just have to apply templates on this model to generate your code (typically DAO, CRUD Screens, etc).

It can be used to generate a Java persistence layer with any kind technology ( JDBC, JPA, etc )

See http://www.telosys.org/ and its "Database model" http://www.telosys.org/models.html

Some ready to use templates are available on GitHub. See : http://www.telosys.org/templates.html, 
https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3